# WSO2 DS Scheduled Task in clustered environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I am going to have two WSO2 EI 660 instances in cluster environment. Every instance needs to have DS Scheduled Task configured - such task reads data from my database every 10 seconds. But I want to ensure that only one task works at the time i.e. it works on only one EI instance and if this instance stops working for some reason then the task on second instance takes over.
Is it possible to achieve this using proper WSO2 configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can cluster the 2 EI servers. In a cluster a task will be scheduled in one node at a time. For any reason if the node that runs the task stops, all the tasks will be scheduled in the 2nd node. Therefore you can achieve your requirement with clustering the EI servers. Please refer to the documentation [1] to further clarify the steps you need to follow to cluster the servers.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile